# How to annotate dependencies in an inline controller while configuring app routes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, annotations

I'm getting following error if I don't annotate the dependencies for an inline controller function for a route (I'm using strict DI mode and all other codes are annotated so that js-minification doesn't break my code):

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/strictdi?p0=function(AuthService,%20$state

Here is the logout route code:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider.state('logout', {
     url: '/logout',
     controller: function(AuthService, $state) {        
       AuthService.logout();
       $state.go('login');
     }
  }

}]);
```

Is there any technique to declare inline annotation for the above two dependent services (AuthService, $state) of the inline controller ?

I know the bellow work-around :

```
.state('logout', {
    url: '/logout',
    controller: LogoutController
});


function LogoutController (AuthService, $state) {        
    AuthService.logout();
    $state.go('login');
}
LogoutController.$inject = ['AuthService', '$state'];
```

this works but just wanted to checkout if anyone knows any smart short-cut ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('logout', {
     url: '/logout',
     controller: ['AuthService', '$state', function(AuthService, $state) {        
       AuthService.logout();
       $state.go('login');
     }]
  }
}]);
```

Not sure if that will work. Usually we separate our controllers into files for ease of use, rather than writing them inline in the config.route.js file.

Comment: It worked ! Thanks a lot :)
Didn't try that as I thought it would be an array syntax instead of function.
You are right that controllers are separated out in separate files, but here I just have two lines of logic, so thought not to create overhead of processing another file.

Comment: Happy to have helped!

Comment: Yeah, it will help many others too for sure. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add more details here, this is expected for inline controllers.

See https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate/issues/50.

Either not inline them or add apply  `controller: /* @ngInject */ function(service1){ ... }`.

The /* @ngInject */ tells ngannotate to apply annotation here.